# Transformation of a probability distribution - Random variable function of a CDF?

Tags: probability, data-transformation

I am trying to wrap my head around a certain topic in my notes, but it seems very confusing.

Let $X$ a continuous random variable whose distribution function $F_X$ is strictly increasing on the possible values of $X$. Then $F_X$ has an inverse function. [Agreed]

Let $U = F_X(X)$, then for $u \in [0,1]$ we wish to find $F_U(u)$:
Since $F_U(u) = P[U\leq u]:$
$$P[U \leq u] = P[F_X(X)\leq u] \; \; \; \; \ \;\;\;(1)$$ 
$$= P[X \leq F_X^{-1}(u)]\; \; \; \; \ \;\;\;(2)$$
$$= F_X(F_X^{-1}(u))=u\; \; \; \; \ \;\;\; (3)$$

I am probably missing something super obvious, but I am confused by the above 3 steps.

From $(1)$ to $(2)$ - I recognise that we defined $U = F_X(X)$, so the LHS is fine.
But the right hand side of the inequality in $(2)$, how exactly does that make sense?

From $(2)$ to $(3)$,  I think it is saying this is just the CDF of $U<F_X^{-1}(u)$? IS that correct? And the inverse cancels with $F_X$ to leave $u$.

I.e., $F_U(u) = u$

Comment: Eq 2 should be P(X<= ...)

Comment: I'm quite certain this is covered by answers already on site.

Comment: Search for 'inverse CDF method'. Many hits.

Comment: Perhaps a more effective search is [Probability Integral Transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for $F_X^{-1}$ to exist, $F_X$  must be strictly increasing *and* continuous.

Second, if $F_X(X)\le u$, then, $F_X$ being increasing, $F_X^{-1}$ is also increasing, hence
$$F_X^{-1}(F_X(X))\le F_X^{-1}(u)$$
by applying $F_X^{-1}$ to both sides of the inequality.

Third, since $F_X^{-1}$ is the inverse function, $$F_X^{-1}(F_X(X))=X$$ hence the event $$U\le u$$ is the same as the event $$X\le F_X^{-1}(u)$$ which has probability$$F_X(F_X^{-1}(u))=u$$

In conclusion, **$U=F_X(X)$ is thus distributed as $\mathcal U(0,1)$ when $X\sim F_X$.**

Comment: Thanks - a typo in the source was leading to some confusion.
makes sense now!